# SQL code not working properly. Output keeps changing (Varying)

Tags: sql, row-number

```
Select * from 
(SELECT * ,   
    (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY age) ) as rn FROM `usr`    
ORDER BY  sname ASC ) temp 
where (`rn` = 2) and (location="Sz")
```

Hi,
when I test this code in phpmyadmin, it returns different values each time run.

Comment: You don't order your ROW_NUMBER, so you have no control over which row per `age` is returned. In other words, put you current `ORDER BY` after the `PARTITION BY`

Comment: HoneyBadger has given you the answer why your results are not deterministic. Now, if you want help with writing the correct query, tell us what the query is supposed to do.

Comment: @Thaviraj Junglee using PARTION you should create at least two parameter in ORDER BY query, to make sure output are kept the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A table and  also a result set is **unsorted**, only when you give the data an `ORDER BY` you get deterministic results.

also your query should look **like** this, in case you want the second.
oldest

But it would be better like MatBailie mentioned in the comment to have another column as sorting order , because if many have 60, i still think that you will get always the same result, but to control the results better another column for sorting would help.

```
Select * from 
(SELECT * ,   
    (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY age ORDER BY age DESC) ) as rn FROM `usr`    
ORDER BY  sname ASC ) temp 
where (`rn` = 2) and (location='Sz')
```

Comment: The `ORDER BY` (the one not in the ROW_NUMBER) would make more sense in the outer query too. Also, I'm not a fan of unnecessary parantheses, nor of double quotes around literal strings

Comment: mysql doesn't mind double quotes , but i will change it. The parenthesis don't really matter

Comment: I know mysql allows them, and that the parantheses don't functionally matter. But readability counts too, though that is personal preference, of course

Comment: `PARTITION BY x ORDER BY x` is still non-deterministic. Your `ORDER BY` should not be the same as the `PARTITION BY`

Comment: running the row_number with order by, even with the same column, will be deterministic., but i agree it would better to have an ordering Column, i will adept it that